# geometric sum evaluation for negative powers

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

How can I evaluate this sum?

$$\sum\limits_{t=1}^N k^{-t}$$

Comment: sub $r=\frac{1}{R}$ and subtract the first term.

Comment: That is exactly what I have written in my notebook. So yes.(unless we are both wrong)

Comment: Sure ... ask away

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
R^{\frac{N(N+1)}{2}} \frac{(R^N-1)}{R^N(R-1)} =\frac{R^{\frac{N(N+1)}{2}}-R^{\frac{N(N-1)}{2}}}{R-1}
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

$R^{-m} = \left( \frac{1}{R} \right)^m$